# Need a variable value in LWC Datatable columns constructor

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC Component with a datatable with lookup which works fine. I now would need a Variable Value in a datatable column constructor to filter values for a lookup field.
Here are the relevant parts I have:

```
import ORDER_EffectiveDate_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Order.EffectiveDate';
export default class OrderProductsList extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@api orderid;
@wire(getRecord, {recordId : '$orderid', fields: [ORDER_STATUS_FIELD, ORDER_EffectiveDate_FIELD]}) order ;

getIssueLookupFilter() {
    console.log(this.order);
    if (this.order.data != 'undefined') {
        console.log(this.order.data);
        let orderStartDate = getFieldValue(this.order.data , ORDER_EffectiveDate_FIELD);
        return 'ClosingDateAds__c > ' + orderStartDate;
    }
    return '';
}
columnsEditProducts =  [
{ label: 'Issue', fieldName: 'Issue__c', type: 'lookup', initialWidth: 200, typeAttributes: {
        placeholder: 'Select Issue',
        uniqueId: { fieldName: 'Id' }, //pass Id of current record to lookup for context
        object: "Issue__c",
        icon: "standard:news",
        label: "Issue",
        displayFields: "Name",
        displayFormat: "Name",
        filters: this.getIssueLookupFilter(),
        valueId: { fieldName: 'Issue__c' }}}
];
get isData() {
    //return this.listorderproducts ? this.listorderproducts.length > 0 : false ;
    return this.order.data != 'undefined' ? true : false;
}
```

And the HTML Part:

```
<template if:true={isData}>
<c-custom-data-table
            key-field="Id"
            data={listorderproducts}               
            draft-values={draftValues}
            columns={columnsEditProducts}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            is-loading={tableLoadingState}
            sorted-by={sortBy}
            sorted-direction={sortDirection}
            onsort={handleSortNumber}
            onsave={handleSave}
            hide-checkbox-column="true"
            onvalueselect={handleSelection}
            onpicklistchanged={picklistChanged} 
            oncellchange={handleCellChange}
           >
        </c-custom-data-table>
```

I guess the issue is, that the order data is not there, when the datatable renders. Or does anyone have an idea on how to reach the goal, having a variable in the comlumns constructor?